# How can I reference an Object and edit it's properties from a NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSMutableArray *persons = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ];
```

How can I edit person attributes without doing something like:

```
Person *p = [ [ Person alloc ] init ];
p = [ persons objectAtIndex:0 ];
p.name = "James Foo";
[ persons replaceObjectAtIndex: ([ persons count ] - 1 )  withObject:p];
```

I would like to do something like:

```
[ persons objectAtIndex:0 ].name = "James Foo";
```

Comment: It should be `@"James Foo"`.  You need the `@` sign in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

But you can. You have to cast the generic id into your type though:

((Person*)[persons objectAtIndex:0]).name = "James Foo";

Comment: Or use the setter directly. `[[persons objectAtIndex:0] setName:@"Foo"]`

Answer (score 2):

This example code also has a memory leak; you shouldn't need to alloc a new person instance in that case; you could just do the following if you don't want to cast anything:

```
Person *p = [persons objectAtIndex:0];
p.name = @"James Foo";
```

and you don't need to re-add it to the array since getting the object at a location doesn't remove it from the array on its own.

Comment: Thanks, I'm newbie on iPhone and Objective C and i'm trying to follow best practices!

Comment: Best practices are for those who understand the rationale behind them. Try to get something out of the door first, then read up on best practices. Premature optimization, blah blah.